# How do you use splice method to separate words entered from a prompt and assign them to variables?

Tags: javascript, prompt, indexof, slice

//I'm trying to enter 4 words through a prompt and split them up and assign each word to a variable

```
var answer = prompt("Enter a sentence");

for(var i = 0; i < answer.length; i++){
    if(answer[i] === " "){
    var firstWord = answer.slice(0, answer.indexOf(" "));
    var secondWord = answer.slice(answer.indexOf(" ") + 1, name.indexOf(" "));
    var thirdWord = answer.slice();
    var fourthWord = answer.slice();
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use `answer.trim().split(/\s+/)` to split it by whitespace characters. It will return a list of the words, but punctuation will still be there.

Comment: Your question title says `splice`. Your question text uses `slice`. Your intent is neither to splice nor slice, but to "separate", which sounds like "split". Take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of a string's `.split()` method.

solution:

```
var answer = prompt("Enter a sentence");

var words = answer.split(" ");
var firstWord = words[0];
var secondWord = words[1];
var thirdWord = words[2];
var fourthWord = words[3];
```

This is dependent on having your prompt separated with a single whitespace and you are only entering 4 words. `.split()` is a method that will look at the string that called it, and split up the string into an array, separated by the parameter value (in this case " ").

[String.prototype.split() Documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)